# Construct $\mathbb{R}$ with general topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading a textbook on general topology. There is a surjective map from the set of integers to the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$, so $\mathbb{Q}$ is countably infinite. This is not the case for $\mathbb{R}$, thus $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

I am wondering how to construct $\mathbb{R}$ with order relation $<$, open set $(a,b)$, etc., based on point-set topology. In other words, how to construct a set of ordered items, each of which can map to one element from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Did you mean *surjective* when you typed *subjective*?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question. Why don't any of [the standard constructions of $\mathbb{R}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Explicit_constructions_of_models) satisfy your requirements?

Comment: If it's the order you're after, the [Dedekind cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) construction of the reals seems appropriate.